# Batch use of | symbol

Tags: batch-file

What is "|" symbol used for in batch?

Because its not a command I cant use `| /?` to find out what it does, and if I have something like `Stackoverflow|Stackoverflow` (as an example) I'm told "stackoverflow is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe operator `|` directs (pipes) the output of the first command to the standard input of the second command. So running

```
somecmd | anothercmd
```

Would first run `somecmd`, then gather the output of `somecmd` and run `anothercmd`, giving it the output of `somecmd` as input. You can read about it in innumerable places, just google "pipe command line" or something like it.

Comment: So it like using '>' but the output is being sent to a command not a file

Comment: @GarethJones yep, that's basically it.

Comment: @GarethJones: In terms of the command *after* the pipe operator, you could also say that `|` is like `<` but the input is taken from a command, not from a file.

Comment: `Com1 | Com2` is equivalent to execute `Com1>tempfile & Com2<tempfile & del tempfile`. In the case of the pipe, the tempfile is managed by the OS.

Answer (score 4):

It's the pipe operator, or redirect operator. From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx):

> Reads the output from one command and writes it to the input of another command. Also known as a pipe.
>
> The pipe operator (|) takes the output (by default, STDOUT) of one command and directs it into the input (by default, STDIN) of another command. For example, the following command sorts a directory:
>
> dir | sort
>
> In this example, both commands start simultaneously, but then the sort command pauses until it receives the dir command's output. The sort command uses the dir command's output as its input, and then sends its output to handle 1 (that is, STDOUT).

Answer (score 1):

This character is used to chain commands.

There's a lot of documentation available on this. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) is probably a good place to start.